# Create a table splitting comma and finding unique elements

Tags: excel

I have the following data

```
Person     Week1
P1         L,L
P2         M,H
```

Output I would like is

```
Person      Week1
           L   M   H
P1         2   0   0
P2         0   1   1
```

My intention is to create a chart based on the output so I can figure out how many codes a person got per week. Pivot tables does not seem to work for this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure formula approach.

Its based off of two basic formulas.  The first formula is how to count the number of times a string A occurs within string B.  This is done, by counting the number of characters in the string B, then by counting the number of characters in String B after string A has been replaced by nothing or "".  If string A is more than 1 character long you need to divide the result by the length of string A.  That gives us this formula:

```
=(LEN(STRING B)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(STRING B, STRING A, "")))/LEN(STRING A)
```

Now we know how to count the number of time L, M or H occur as they are string A and now we need to determine string B.

IF we look at the first table, it has nice row headers and column hearders.  We could take a short cut and just assume everything is in order however I am going to go with the more generic approach in case the headers happen to be in a random order.

Basically we need to find out what column in the first table matches with the header in our second table.  ie is week2 really the second column?  is P1 still the first row?  in order to do that we use the following

```
=MATCH("WEEK X",$B$1:$D$1,0)
and 
=MATCH("PX",$A$2:$A$3,0)
```

Those will return an integers which we can then drop into the an INDEX function to locate and find the text in the first table:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$3,MATCH("PX",$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH("WEEK X",$B$1:$D$1,0))
```

AWESOME we now know how to find the text from the table to drop into our counting formula that we started with.  That las formula gets substituted into wherever there is STRING B!

```
=(LEN(INDEX($B$2:$D$3,MATCH("PX",$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH("WEEK X",$B$1:$D$1,0)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($B$2:$D$3,MATCH("PX",$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH("WEEK X",$B$1:$D$1,0)), STRING A, "")))/LEN(STRING A)
```

yeah its getting a little ugly isn't it!  String A is then whatever cell L is in in your second table.  Replace "Week X" with your week header in your second table.  Replace "PX" with the name of your person in your second table.

I would do the first formula, then copy it over under the M and under the H.  Go into the M and H formula and adjust it so its pointing at the right week header in each.  Lock the row but not the column references for the week header and the string A cells.  Lock the column but not the row for the persons name.  once you have that set up, copy al three formulas and paste under each week.  Then just copy your entire first row of table two down for the number of people you have and voila!

Proof of concept

[image: Proof of concept]

The formula I used in Cells H3, I3, and K3 respectively

```
=(LEN(INDEX($B$2:$D$3,MATCH($G3,$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH(H$1,$B$1:$D$1,0)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($B$2:$D$3,MATCH($G3,$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH(H$1,$B$1:$D$1,0)),H$2,"")))/LEN(H$2)

=(LEN(INDEX($B$2:$D$3,MATCH($G3,$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH(H$1,$B$1:$D$1,0)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($B$2:$D$3,MATCH($G3,$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH(H$1,$B$1:$D$1,0)),I$2,"")))/LEN(I$2)

=(LEN(INDEX($B$2:$D$3,MATCH($G3,$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH(H$1,$B$1:$D$1,0)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($B$2:$D$3,MATCH($G3,$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH(H$1,$B$1:$D$1,0)),J$2,"")))/LEN(J$2)
```

Here is another proof of concept with expanded range showing rows out of order, and multiple letter strings to be searching for and more than two entries.  Same formulas, just had to adjust the look up ranges for the increased table size.

[image: Proof of concept 2]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the efforts. Instead of asking excel to create the new output table, i am already creating a table and under L , I want to write a formula to look into the cell corresponding in the input table and find count of L.. Same i want to do under M and under H.

Comment: @user238021 Does the picture above do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If using VBA is acceptable, splitting the comma separated data using [TextToColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) should help as a first processing step.

Then using a pivot table gives you the output you want.

Comment: I am not familiar with VBA.  Sorry

Comment: So I have created a new table that matches my output. In that table, I am trying to figure out how i can split the cell with delimiter , (if there is ,) and then count with a condition (if split value == "L").

Comment: Using the macro recorder usually gives a good starting point for working VBA code. Next step could be reading the docs for the referenced functions in the recorded code.